# Not able to set the cookie on the browser

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a blog-creating site that authenticates the user by checking the jwt token which is stored in the cookie. It is working fine on my local machine but when I deployed my backend on Azure VM and deployed my frontend on Azure app services, that's where it is causing the problem, the browser is not able to set the cookie on the browser.

here is the code of index.js

const express = require("express");

const dbconnection = require("./database/dbconnect");

const authRoute = require("./routes/authRoutes.js");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute.js");

const blogRoute = require("./routes/blogRoute.js");

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const cors = require("cors");

const PORT = 8000;

dbconnection();

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));

// app.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

app.use((req, res, next) => {

// Set CORS headers

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", process.env.FRONTEND_URL); // Replace with your frontend domain

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); // Allow credentials (cookies, etc.)

// Pass to next layer of middleware

next();

});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/", authRoute);

app.use("/user", userRoute);

app.use("/blog", blogRoute);

app.listen(PORT, () => {

console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);

});

here is the code for login.js

const User = require("../database/model/user");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const env = require("dotenv");

const { createSecretToken } = require("../tokenGeneration/generateToken");

env.config();

const login = async (req, res) => {

const { email, password } = req.body;

if (!(email && password)) {

return res.status(400).json({ message: "All input is required" });

}

const user = await User.findOne({ email });

if (!(user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)))) {

return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid credentials" });

}

const token = createSecretToken(user._id);

console.log(token)

res.cookie("token", token, {

domain:'.bloggle-vista.azurewebsites.net',

path: "/",

httpOnly: true,

secure: true,

sameSite:"None"

});

res.json({ token });

};

module.exports = login;

Comment: Hi, please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Thank you

Answer (score -1):

use jwt token instead of this

```
/* status codes */
const {
  ReasonPhrases,
  StatusCodes,
  getReasonPhrase,
  getStatusCode,
} = require("http-status-codes");
const JWT = require("jsonwebtoken");
/* dotenv */
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
    // dotEnv Configuration
dotenv.config();
/* models */
const User = require("../models/user.model");
const signToken = (id) => {
  return JWT.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SEC, {
    expiresIn: process.env.expirydateJwt,
  });
};
```

jwt token is widely accepted for do this job

use signToken function for get token

make .env file

```
JWT_SEC=Abdul Wadood
expirydateJwt=3d
CRYPTO_SEC=Abdul Wadood
```

download dotenv and jsonwebtoken packages

packages:

```
npm i jsonwebtoken dotenv
```

Comment: remove 

/* status codes */
const {
  ReasonPhrases,
  StatusCodes,
  getReasonPhrase,
  getStatusCode,
} = require("http-status-codes");

because i added it my mistake 

happy coding

ask me more if you have more questions

Comment: Thank you Abdul, this bug is resolved. Actually I did a silly mistake.

Comment: sahil plz upvote my answer and support me @SahilBisht